# What is "HotfixLevel 2" in Delphi XE7?

Tags: delphi, ide, version, delphi-xe7, hotfix

I have found

> "HotfixLevel"=dword:00000002

in the registry of a previous installment of Delphi XE7. The current installment does not have this key. What does it mean? There are other updates beyond Update 1?

The key is located in:

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\15.0]

I have Delphi XE7 Update 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hot fixes are updates released outside the normal update schedule. It seems that you have, on one of your Delphi installations, installed the hot fix identified by that value.

Comment: Yes. I see this. But which one? How did I get it? :) Do you think it was installed by Delphi's background updater? Weird to ask the Internet about who installed updates in MY computer? :) It must be the autoupdater.... But I don't remember to ever get a notification from that updater. I got an electronic download containing Update1 (5GB) from Embarcadero and since then the updater never did something.

Comment: Hot fixes aren't installed automatically.  FWIW, full updates are not installed automatically.  A human is responsible for this.  If you want all your installations to be the same, you should reinstall.

Comment: That's what I did, I reinstalled from the same ISO.

Comment: Did you delete that entry from the registry before reinstalling?

Comment: Yes. What I did was to reinstall the whole OS and Delphi. Then I compared the current registry with the old ones (from previous Win installation) . The old registry contain the key. The new registry don't.